# Exchangeability of R.V.'s

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, measure-theory, order-statistics

Let $X_0$,$X_1$,....,$X_n$ denote i.i.d. real valued r.v.'s.

For every definition of $Y_1$,...,$Y_n$ below, say whether or not $Y_1$,...,$Y_n$ are exchangeable and justify your answer.

1. $Y_j$ = $X_j$ - $X_0$, j = 1,...,n
2. $Y_j$ = $X_j$ - $X_{j-1}$ , j = 1,...,n
3. $Y_j$ = $X_j$ - $\bar{X}$, j = 1,...,n where $\bar{X}$ = $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j/n $
4. $Y_j$ = (j/n)$X_j$ + (1 - j/n)$X_0$, j = 1,...,n

I. Yes, since each $X_j$ is subtracting the same value, and since each $X_j$ is i.i.d., $Y_j$ is exchangeable.

II. No, since each $X_j$ depends upon the previous $X_{j-1}$.

III. Yes, each $X_j$ is simply subtracting the mean of $X_j$'s. This should have no effect on their exchangeability.

IV. Not sure.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning from II onward. For example in II, you probably meant $Y_j$ depends on $Y_{j-1}$, yet this isn't sufficient to rule out exchangeability. As an example, let $Y_1=Y_2=X_1$. Clearly $P(Y_1,Y_2)=P(Y_2,Y_1)$, yet $Y_1$ depends on $Y_2$. In other words, to show a sequence is not exchangeable, you must exhibit a configuration and permutation whose joint density isn't equal to the joint density of the original sequence $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$.

Comment: To keep your calculations simplified, in the parts where you want to show the $Y_j$'s are not (necessarily) exchangeable, specialize to the case where (say) $X_j$'s are (independent) uniform distributions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah, ok. So if each $X_j$ has a probability of .1 (say there are $X_0$ through $X_9$), then obviously 1-3 would be exchangeable. #1 would always result in (.1)-(.1) =0, #2 would result in  (.1)-(.1) =0, and #3 would result in (.1)-(.1) =0. 

I believe 4 would be exchangeable as well. For example, if we have $X_1$, then we would have (.1)(.1)+ (.9)(.1) = .1

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the meaning of i.i.d., independent identically distributed random variables.  It is not a matter of each of these having "a probability of .1", but that each $X_j$ takes values according to independent but identical distributions.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

The Yes/No answers to 1.-3. are correct although I have no idea what their justifications in the post mean (and, as mentioned in comments, you should definitely check the meaning of "i.i.d."). To solve 4., assume the random variables $X_j$ are square integrable and note that, for every $j\ne k$, the covariance of $Y_j$ and $Y_k$ is $(1-j/n)(1-k/n)$ times the variance of $X_0$ hence, except in some degenerate cases, $(Y_j)$ is not exchangeable.